# Unable to reach Windows server: "Please wait for the Local Session Manager"

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, vsphere

When connecting to our Windows Server 2008 R2 desktop via MS Rdp tool (latest version), occasionally the connection is closing after displaying "Please wait for the Local Session Manager". The result is that I am unable to get into Windows desktop.

Searching the web gives me a hotfix from Microsoft (https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/2661001/-please-wait-for-local-session-manager-message-remains-for-several-minutes-when-you-disconnect-from-a-computer-that-is-running-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2-during-the-logon-process) which doesn't seem to be downloadable any more.

Also the tip to delete some "usrclass.dat" files did not work (
https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/291092-please-wait-for-the-local-session-manager/?p=1624478) because the files can't be deleted since they're "in use".

Only solution is to reboot Windows, but that's highly impractical for a production web server.

Windows is running virtually on VMWare's Vsphere.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting usrclass.dat DID the trick here. But of course you have to delete this file logged in with admin-account...